# Can I install 64 bit Ubuntu on my Intel Core i7 64bit

Tags: 64-bit

i have Dell Insoiron 15R intel core i7

so here the Question is ubuntu 14.10 desktop amd64 will work with intel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the links:

[Hardware catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/search/?query=core%20I7)

[Dell certified laptops](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?query=15R&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&release=&level=Any&vendors=Dell)

Most likely it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Eva Eva,
Yes, Ubuntu 14.10 will definitely work with Intel Core i7 64bit
Just make sure you grab the Ubuntu Desktop 14.10 64bit version and you should have no problems.
Just go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/ and choose 64bit recommended as your flavour.
Best thing to do is to try it out first without installing to make sure that the rest of the hardware is also compatible.  After downloading you can put Ubuntu either on a USB flash drive or on a disc and when you re-boot your pc choose the option to "Try" instead of "Install" so that you can make sure everything works.  If it works, then you can install straight from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will. You can download that [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04.1&architecture=amd64)